# Importing CSV file into MySQL only loads 1 row

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Goal: I have a folder that contains a large number of CSV files (comma delimited). I want to loop through each file and load it into a single MySQL table and include the filename as a column in the table.

I expect the code to load the entire contents of each file. But it only loads 1 row of data for each file. The code comes from a book so in theory it should work. My hope is that there is a small adjustment needed to make it work vs having to start from scratch. I've read several other posts but didn't find this specific issue.

I am on Windows 10. Python code below. I am not a programmer or experienced with python but am learning.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/myDB')

data_location = 'C://folder//'

def import_file(symbol):
    path = data_location + '{}.csv'.format(symbol)
    df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])

    # part one
    insert_init = """insert into table
        (date, ticker, open, high, low, close, volume, dividend)
        values 
        """

    # part two - add values 
    vals = ",".join(["""('{}', '{}', {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})""".format(
        str(day),
        symbol,
        row.open,
        row.high,
        row.low,
        row.close,
        row.volume,
        row.dividend
     ) for day, row in df.iterrows()]) 

    # part three - Handle dups
        insert_end = """  on duplicate key update 
        open=values(open),
        high=values(high),
        low=values(low),
        close=values(close),
        volume=values(volume),
        dividend=values(dividend),"""

    # Put the parts together
    query = insert_init + vals + insert_end

    engine.execute(query)

def process_symbols():
    symbols = [s[:-4] for s in os.listdir(data_location)]
    for symbol in tqdm_notebook(symbols, desc='Importing...'):
        import_file(symbol)
     process_symbols()
```

The MySQL table has the elements in "part one" of the code and uses both date and ticker as primary keys.

I don't get any error messages.

Any idea why it only loads 1 row?

Query output:

```
insert into table 
    (date, ticker, open, high, low, close, volume, dividend)
     values
     ('1999-11-18 00:00:00', 'A', 50.24309847871317, 50.24309847871317, 50.24309847871317, 50.24309847871317, 58425783.68, 0.0)
     ,('1999-11-19 00:00:00', 'A', 51.092206843003424, 51.092206843003424, 51.092206843003424, 51.092206843003424, 19084157.7, 0.0)
     ,('1999-11-22 00:00:00', 'A', 50.39224360925426, 50.39224360925426, 50.39224360925426, 50.39224360925426, 8310053.22, 0.0)
     ,('1999-11-23 00:00:00', 'A', 49.44990865376121, 49.44990865376121, 49.44990865376121, 49.44990865376121, 5328834.84, 0.0)
     ,('1999-11-24 00:00:00', 'A', 48.609260206647264, 48.609260206647264, 48.609260206647264, 48.609260206647264, 5861663.3999999985, 0.0)  
on duplicate key update 
        open=values(open),
        high=values(high),
        low=values(low),
        close=values(close),
          volume=values(volume),
        dividend=values(dividend);
```

Comment: What do you see if you look at your `query` variable? That's a good place to start troubleshooting this. And start with a small CSV file, then progress to larger ones.

Comment: So you load a file and where do loop over every row to insert and insert it? Also it exist prepared statements with parameters, that seem ideally for that purpose.  Also you could mysql do the job, but a loop with inserts is ok

Comment: @O.Jones: I reduced a file to 5 rows but it still only loaded the first row. The query output does show all 5 rows. I do notice that there are parenthesis added around each row. Might mySQL be reading this as a line termination? I tried to edit the code to not include parenthesis but got syntax errors (not sure how to do that). And I don't know if that is the issue. I added the query output above.

Comment: @nbk: I did find some other functions for looping through files and loading them. But adding the file name to a column doesn't seem to be a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: Yes, that is why i mentioned it. It would be perfect for your purpose, but your code is still open to sql injection, so i still think you should guive it a try, especially if you don't know where the csv are comming from

Comment: @nbk: sorry, what would be perfect for my purpose? I am not sure what specific approach you are suggesting.

Comment: using prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: I solved the issue by creating a combined unique key with two columns. Then it worked.